# Math.Abs() in Javascript - array unexpected

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

If i pass array in Math.abs() I cannot understand why it returns -3, why my value is changing from positive to negative

```
let test1 = [2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]
let test2 = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1]
function firstDuplicate(a) {
  for (let i of a) {
    console.log(i);
    let posi = Math.abs(i) - 1;
    //console.log(posi);
  }

}
console.log(firstDuplicate(test1))
console.log(firstDuplicate(test2))
```

and I don't understand how Math.abs is working, real code is below

```
function firstDuplicate(a) {
  for (let i of a) {
    let posi = Math.abs(i) - 1
    if (a[posi] < 0) return posi + 1
    a[posi] = a[posi] * -1
  }

  return -1
}
```

Comment: please add the result and the wanted result as well.

Comment: please observe that you are multiplying with -1   a[posi] = a[posi] * -1

Answer (score 2):

Math.abs() returns absolute value of number. But u re multiplying your absolute value by negative 1. thats why you get negative value

```
a[posi] = a[posi] * -1
```

Comment: Can you please explain me this code because I am not able to understand how it is finding first duplicate

Comment: that need to be asked as another question

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some flaws.

```
  for (let i of a) { 
    let posi = Math.abs(i) - 1
    if (a[posi] < 0) return posi + 1
    a[posi] = a[posi] * -1
  }
```

Lets step through this, step by step with an example:

1. **(let i of a)** will give you each value in the arrray. e.g. on first loop *i=2*
2. **let posi = Math.abs(i) - 1** will convert the number from the array to an absolute integer and substract 1. Now *posi* would be (2 - 1) = 1.
3. **a[posi]** will now get the value from the array at index *1* which is *3* (in array test1)
4. **if (a[posi] < 0) return posi + 1** this will never return unless there is a negative number or *0* somewhere in your data (Math.abs(0) - 1 === -1).
5. **a[posi] = a[posi] * -1** Now you change the value in your array. In our example: a[1] = a[1] * -1. This will leave the array in the following state: **[2, -3, 3, 1, 5, 2]**

I hope that this helps you to understand your own code. Maybe google for a solution on "how to find first duplicate in aray" and just copy that.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, This code is from google and works perfectly but I am confused how this code is working properly and given expected result